# how to use clang with libmvec glibc's short vector math library

Tags: llvm, clang++

It is possible to use gcc with short vector math library (libmvec) with -ftree-vectorize and -ffast-math. I want to ask how to use libmvec with clang. I figure out there is an option -fveclib= for clang. But it does not accept  -fveclib=libmvec.

https://godbolt.org/z/jqsbSu

Comment: This is something you will need to patch clang+llvm or file a feature request for. I was thinking the other FOSS vector math library (SLEEF) should be available, but [oops they closed that PR by accident](https://reviews.llvm.org/D53927). For now you are screwed.

Answer (score 1):

As of LLVM 12, you can use `-fveclib=libmvec` to force CLANG to use libmvec. If your code uses mathematical functions (`sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `pow`) you can experience a large improvement in performance.